# Copy row to next empty row of another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy rows into a new sheet based on several criteria.

I managed to write a macro that can find a row and copy it to a new sheet but unfortunately I'm overwriting the previous entries.

There are some Solutions to this on stackoverflow - I searched for things like "copy rows into a new sheet in empty row" etc. - but I just couldn't make them work by just copying some of the code in these answers (without a proper understanding of the code).

How do I copy the results to the next empty row in the new sheet?

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim criterion As String
Dim team1 As String
Dim team2 As String
Dim team3 As String

criterion = "done"
team1 = "source"
team2 = "refine"
team3 = "supply"


Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents

With Worksheets("Actions")
    .range("$A:$F").AutoFilter
    'filter for actions that are not "done"
    .range("$A:$F").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & criterion
    'filter for actions where "due date" is in the past
    .range("$A:$F").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Date)

    'FIRST TEAM
    .range("$A:$F").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & team1
    'iff overdue actions exist, copy them into "Sheet3"
    lastRow = .range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    If (lastRow > 1) Then
        .range("A1:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").range("A1")
    End If

    'SECOND TEAM
    .range("$A:$F").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & team2
    'iff overdue items exist, copy them into "Sheet3"
    lastRow = .range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    If (lastRow > 1) Then
        'find last row with content and copy relevant rows
        .range("A1:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").range("A1")
    End If

    'THIRD STREAM
    .range("$A:$F").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & team3
    'iff overdue items exist, copy them into "Sheet3"
    lastRow = .range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    If (lastRow > 1) Then
        'find last row with content and copy relevant rows
        .range("A1:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").range("A1")
    End If

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use your LastRow Code again in the new sheet.

so try

```
If (lastRow > 1) Then
    LastRow2 = worksheets("Sheet3").range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row + 1
    'find last row with content and copy relevant rows
    .range("A1:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").range("A" & LastRow2)
End If
```

This finds the last used row of your sheet 3 and will paste it below it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I will try that now :)

Comment: Hi again, it works, thank you! Now I just have to find a way to avoid copying the Header over and over again, haha :D

Comment: If your headers are in the first row then change your copy bit from .range("A1:A" & lastrow) to .range("A2:A" & lastrow)

Comment: Hey, yeah, I tried that and it worked. Thanks anyway for your comment! I'm starting to understand VBA a bit better :)